# Select column in one row and save as variable using python and mysqldb

Tags: php, python, mysql, mysql-python

first sorry for my bad english. i'm php programmer and I just started a python programming language.

Mysql code:

```
SELECT * FROM `datapy` ORDER BY `No` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

And show row:

```
++++++++++++++++++
++ NO +++ nilai ++
++++++++++++++++++
++ 12 +++  100  ++
++++++++++++++++++
```

in php it's very easy for select column and save as variable using:

```
$row = $takecolumn['nilai'];
```

What should I do if in python using mysqldb?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a database object like `db` and use `cursor()`

```
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute("select nilai from datapy ORDER BY `No` DESC LIMIT 0,1")
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: http://ianhowson.com/a-quick-guide-to-using-mysql-in-python.html visit this site (Y)

Comment: whether it would only take the "value"? or take entirely?

Comment: it's store whole query result in `rows` you can fetch all value ..use loop.....sorry for my bad english @Eightleven

Comment: so, i want take "nilai" column and the script is `rows = cur.fetchall(nilai)` ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html     refer this site

Comment: if that is not possible if not using the loop?, if yes please give me complete code for take data in "nilai" column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117657/discussion-between-dipnesh-and-eightleven).